# Is it possible to disable the automatic linking of images in github markdown rendering?

Tags: github, markdown

When github.com renders an image in a readme.md, it automatically links the image in an `a` tag.

Using either

```
![][http://example.com/path/image]
```

or

```
<img src="http://example.com/path/image" />
```

The actual rendered content will appear as

```
<a href="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8a545f12e16ff12fd...." target="_blank"><img src="https://camo.githubusercontent.com/8a545f12e16ff12f..." alt="" data-canonical-src="http://example.com/path/image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
```

I understand the [github image caching](https://help.github.com/articles/why-do-my-images-have-strange-urls/) (on camo.githubusercontent.com), and that's fine, but I don't want the `a` tag to wrap my image.

I'm not sure if this is part of the github flavored automatic URL linking, or something specific images.

I am able to provide my own link (using my own `a` tag), but what I really want is no link, no `a` tag.

Is this possible?

thanks!

Comment: Do you still want the image displayed, or do you just want the URL to be displayed as text?

Comment: I want the image displayed, but no link added.

Comment: Presumably, this is something that GitHub has built into their Markdown parser. There is not any different Markdown syntax that eludes this behavior. So, I'm afraid its not possible, which is one of the tradeoffs with hosting your documents on something other than your own server. You loose control of how things work.

Answer (score 48):

You can wrap the image in a link that points to `#`:

```
[![](http://example.com/path/image)](#)

<a href="#"><img src="http://example.com/path/image" /></a>
```

It will still be clickable, but won't open a new page, at least.

Comment: That doesn't really help in any way... The transition is still distracting and I think people would prefer to be linked to image in a new card rather than getting to the top of the page in order to scroll down again...

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't help in any way, it helps to keep the reader in the same page which while not great it's still clearly better than sending them off elsewhere

Comment: Good method, but if you use it with your Github profile readme, clicking on a `#` link results in weird visual glitches in the left column of your profile (under the photo).

Comment: Using the Markdown option now actually removes the link!

Comment: @flyingsheep do you have a working example of this? It's not working for me.

Comment: Sadly It did in the PR preview, but not in the final rendering.

Comment: I wouldn't add #. See my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70467448/3493998

Comment: Note that if you have something like `(#---)` it won't scroll up to the top of the page at least. That's because you are referring to an [anchor](https://gist.github.com/asabaylus/3071099) that doesn't exists `---`, so the browser  doesn't scroll the page.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [`<picture>`](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#specifying-the-theme-an-image-is-shown-to) tag to prevent GitHub from auto linking to the image.

```
<picture>
  <img alt="Image Alt Text" src="http://example.com/path/image">
</picture>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMHO. Works beautifully

Comment: Can confirm, this keeps GitHub from rendering the a element.

Comment: The code presented is incomplete, as Github will attempt to show images based on color scheme (light/dark), so you need to include the full example presented in the link (need to include the full `prefers-color-scheme: dark`/`prefers-color-scheme: light` logic). To test this case, toggle your Github color light/dark schemes in Settings and observe. If done incorrectly, your images will disappear/reappear depending on active light/dark scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `linkImagesToOriginal: false` to `gatsby-remark-images` should be able to resolve this issue.

```js
{
 resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
 options: {
   linkImagesToOriginal: false,
 },
}
```

Comment: ..and how do I apply this configuration to my Github.com contents?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on your badge, you think to see an image, but it is usually a html page with html-tags. That's why badges links to a different page by default.

@Tamás Sengel answer isn't bad, but looks like there were side effects like visual glitches @Igor mentioned.

I solved this problem by simply referring to my github page:

```
[![platform](https://img.shields.io/badge/platform-ubuntu%20%7C%20windows-lightgrey?style=flat-square)](https://github.com/Ismoh/NoitaMP)
```

[image: platform]

It's a static badge build with [shields.io](https://shields.io) and shouldn't link to [source](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/79612e3fc715688785823417ee0a072d6dbed432701d319ee100a96c30e889a1/68747470733a2f2f696d672e736869656c64732e696f2f62616467652f706c6174666f726d2d7562756e747525323025374325323077696e646f77732d6c69676874677265793f7374796c653d666c61742d737175617265).

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below is exactly what you need to "remove" the `a` tag for images. Markdown will render all the `img`'s tags around the `a`. For me (using Gatsby) the option "linkImagesToOriginal: false" removed perfectly and now all the images are NOT clickable.

```js
{
 resolve: 'gatsby-remark-images',
 options: {
   linkImagesToOriginal: false,
 },
}
```

Comment: How is this different than @Auguest G.'s answer, which was ~a year before yours?

Answer (score -1):

This method works the best for me: linking the image to itself

```
<a id="image1" href="#image1"><img alt="alt text" src="http://example.com/path/image.png" /></a>
```